# Subtract music from microphone input while recording

Tags: microphone, audio, recording, software, filtering

I do have a Soundblaster 5/rx with a line-in, my mixer has an aux-return (and if that does not what I think it does, it has a headphone out too which I could use).

The signal that is sent to the speakers and the signal that my mic (connected via USB) picks up is different of course. But the difference should be the same all the time, my microphone does not move.

What I'm currently trying to figure out is if it is possible to subtract the signal that goes to the speakers (music, game noise & other voices from the mixer) from the signal that is handed to communication software. So my mic picks up everything including my voice, some black box removes what my speakers receive (factoring in distortion by playing through speakers and re-recording) and the result (just my voice) will be left over. Is this feasible or just some pipedream?

Edit: spelling

Comment: I recommend Beyerdynamic open ear headphones and bending the metal strap so it’s comfortable. You can wash the pads if they get gross, and the sound quality is phenomenal, something like $160 for those. Sony has studio headphones for about $80 that I liked too. I’m curious if you figure out the echo compensation.. I always had trouble routing audio with VoiceMeeter because of the delay, but you can play lossless 44.1 music or samples through your microphone too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's echo compensation.  Estimating the room transfer function by correlation with the known signal sent to the speakers and subtracting the resulting estimate of its contribution.  Usual algorithm used for that is LMS.

Speakerphone applications need to do that.  Whether you can tune the operation enough to be satisfied for your purposes will require testing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, it's funny how a single (or two in this case) keywords can bring you so much further. I've marked it as the answer as this is exactly what I'm looking for, regardless of if it is going to work or not in my case.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of making things a little simpler, you might want to also consider an expander / gate, which is a form of dynamics insert effect that works like the 'opposite' of a compressor.

This will hold the microphone channel closed until there is input on the channel.